# What is the longitude of the winter solstice for the various planets?

Tags: orbit, planet, coordinate, celestial-mechanics, declination

I am looking for data showing the longitude at which the various planets  in the solar system reach their winter solstice.  Where could I find this data?

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I adjusted your tags and the wording slightly.

Comment: Thanks @B--rian ! Do you have any tips about finding that data?

Comment: Do you mean the declination of the Sun as seen from those planets, or of those planets as seen from Earth?

Comment: @MikeG fair point I mean the first one of those. Any idea where I might find the data? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might find [in-the-sky.org's *Custom astronomical graph plotter* by Dominic Ford](https://in-the-sky.org/graphs.php?gtype=2&duration=8&obj1type=0&obj1txt=Jupiter) helpful. For instance, for Jupiter, a start date of today, you can obtain the declination graph of the next 10 years for a given location (which you can change as well):

[image: Custom astronomical graph plotter]

This does not solve your problem that you want to determine the longitude of maximal declination, but still.